# Alternative closed forms for digamma expressions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

What commands should I use such that Mathematica / W|A express

$$\psi(1+i)+\psi(1-i)$$
exclusively in terms of trigonometric functions?

Comment: Maybe you could help by letting us know which Mathematica command(s) gives "digamma"?

Comment: What is `i` in your function and how does it relate to `x`? (Hint: show code that you have tried).

Comment: I was not the downvoter, but your comment is quite arrogant given how poorly you wrote your question.

Comment: For rational arguments, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Gauss.27s_digamma_theorem may be helpful.

Comment: So you asked to be deleted yesterday and then posted a question today? Asking for your account to be deleted is OK. Defacing stackexchange is not OK. Here are the instructions: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account

Comment: @Chris'ssis Regular users cannot delete other users. I can, but you requested deletion from the Stack Exchange team (employees), so you'll have to wait till they get around to it.

Comment: @rm-rf Ah, I know this very well, but I don't know why I thought Artes is a moderator. My screen here is pretty small and I didn't look for that diamond.

Comment: @Chris'ssis Each site has one - [here's ours](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account). Which account gets deleted depends on what you requested in the text box and which account you linked to. The requests (from each site) all go to the same inbox, so as long as you didn't mess up the link or be vague, you should be good.

Comment: @Chris'ssis I think that deleting your _Mathematica_ account is not fair. You gained much help from the other users and now they will lose all reputation earned from your upvoting. They devoted their time and  effort providing answers and sharing their knowledge. Simply you should just imagine that is really unjust.

Comment: Probably not. Again, I don't know how precisely they follow those requirements, but if they have any questions, they'll contact you via email.

Comment: @rm-rf OK, thank you!

Comment: @Artes OK, agree! I won't delete this account anymore (never).

Answer (score 2):

How about a series expansion?

```
Chop@N@Series[PolyGamma[0, x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

Or try FullSimplify:

```
FullSimplify[PolyGamma[1 - x] - PolyGamma[x]]
π Cot[π x]

FullSimplify[PolyGamma[1 - x] - PolyGamma[1 + x]]
-(1/x) + π Cot[π x]
```

With the plus I get the answer in terms of HarmonicNumbers rather than Trig functions:

```
N@FullSimplify[PolyGamma[1 - x] + PolyGamma[1 + x]]
-1.15443 + HarmonicNumber[-1. x] + HarmonicNumber[x]
```

Comment: Did you know that $\psi(1+i)-\psi(1-i)=i(\pi \coth(\pi)-1)$? I wonder if something similar exists when using addition insted of subtraction. The point is: how can I force Mathematica give me such alternative forms?

Comment: @Chris'ssis: Executing `FullSimplify[PolyGamma[1 + x] + PolyGamma[1 - x]]` gives $H_{-x}+H_x-2 \gamma$ where $H$ is the analytic continuation of the Harmonic number series and where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Gamma constant. Are you sure there exists a trig-function equivalent? If there is, then Mathematica probably can't do it. Also, please stop screaming and whining like an 8-year old in ALL CAPS. It makes you look like a baby.

Comment: I see. Have you tried quitting the kernel and restarting and running it again? I am using version 9 and I get http://imagebin.org/290343. If after restarting and trying again you still get $-\infty$, then it's probably an error in version 8. Mathematica does have glitches sometimes. And I never said you lied. I said that you didn't offer proof, which made it impossible for people to find what is going wrong, which is why everyone downvoted you. I know you're not a liar, and I know you're a very good mathematician. But you need to write your questions clearly to get good answers.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus everything is perfect here. Mathematica simply makes a big mistake. Yesterday morning W|A made the same mistake again and again ... after my post things were fixed.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of W|A giving this glitch?

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus I don't have, but I swear I simply tell you the truth 100%! I have no gain in this!!! I didn't think to make a picture.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12787/discussion-between-dumpsterdoofus-and-chriss-sis)